# Is this a homomorphism? Example of a homomorphism where $f(1_S)\ne 1_T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $f:S\to T$ be a surjective mapping of monoids that holds the homomorphic property: $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. I want to show that $f$ is a homomorphism and also find an example of a mapping that holds the homomorphic property, but not having $f(1_S) = 1_T$.

My attempt is in the answer below.

Comment: Just so you know, I have found that the proper form to including attempts is to put them in your question block.

Comment: @Bib Then I can't discern if it is my question or my answer they are upvoting. I will make a meta thread when I get enough reputations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try the map $f\colon S \to T$ defined by $f(x) = 1_T$ for all $x$.

For a less trivial example consider the ring $A = k[x]/(x^2 - x)$ and let $S = (A, \cdot)$.  Then the map $f\colon S \to S$ defined by $f(a) = ax$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: What is $k[x]$?

Comment: Sorry, let $k = \mathbb R$.  Then $\mathbb R[x]$ is the set of polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients and $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 - x)$ is the set of degree at most one polynomials where, when you multiply you use the rule $x^2 = x$ to reduce the result back down to degree at most $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is homomorphic, as all that is required for homomorpism is that the monoid is properly defined, and that the homomorphic property is satisfied.

An example of a homomorphic mapping $f$ that doesn't have $f(1_S)=1_T$ is $f:S\to T$, $f(x)=e^x$. Clearly $f(x+y)=e^{x+y}=e^x e^y=f(x)\cdot f(y)$. If we take $f:S\to T$ with $S=(\Bbb R, \cdot), T=(\Bbb R, +)$, we have $1_S=1,1_T=0$ and thus $f(1)=e\ne 0$

Comment: First you need to define what $S$ and $T$ are, $e^x$ is not defined for all rings.  Second, by $1_A$ do you mean the identity element of the monoid $A$?  If that's the case and, for example, $S = (\mathbb R, +)$ and $T = (\mathbb R^\ast, \cdot)$ then the identity of the monoid $S$ is $0$, the identity of the monoid $T$ is $1$, and $e^0 = 1$.  So this doesn't work.

Comment: @Jim Wow good point, and yes that is what I meant. I suppose my example broke when I realised that I wrote the homomorpic property wrong in the first edit.

Comment: Well, this is true, but $1$ is not identity of additive monoid, so it is not really counterexample. Rings provide plentiful of examples because they have multiplicative monoids that are not necessarily groups, and there are lots of ring homomorphisms that don't preserve $1$, but we could just take zero morphism.

Comment: @Jim Was the mapping from the opposite direction a working example?(E.g. Multiplicative monoid to the additive monoid)

Comment: Then $e^x$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: @Ennar Thanks for that comment. I am new to this, so I will have to have a long look and explore the examples

Comment: @Jim Ahh damn. I guess I will have to try a different approach. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Let's give you a nontrivial example as well, multiplication by $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. When you have torsion ($6x = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$) you can expect such behavior.

Comment: @Ennar: Do you mean $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ with addition?  We'd still have $0 \mapsto 0$.

Comment: It is a ring homomorphism that does not preserve multiplicative identity.

Comment: Ah, mult instead of addition.  Gotcha.

Comment: @Ennar It is probable I am being silly, but $f(xy)=4(xy)=4xy\ne (4x)(4y)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: $f(xy) = 4xy = 4xy + 6\cdot 2xy = 16xy = (4x)(4y) = f(x)f(y)$ because $6 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.